# Does TCP have to be used in a one to one send/receive fashion?

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm developing an embedded system that connects to a PC over ethernet using TCP sockets.  The PC will be the TCP client, and the embedded system the server.  If I understand it correctly, the classical communication model is that the client sends some data to the server, and the server responds every time.  The server never initiates communication.

What I'd like to do is send commands from the PC to the embedded system, without corresponding  responses.  The embedded system will then execute the tasks described by the commands.  If the embedded system has an error, or has some status message to report back, it will send these back, without being polled by the PC.

I've figured out everything but the receiving on the PC side.  I'm programming the PC app in C#.net  Can I set up a callback that fires whenever data has been received on the socket? Every example I've seen uses the receive method in a blocking fashion.

Comment: A TCP connection gives you a bidirectional connection.  There is no relationship between bytes headed in either direction other than what you define.  Keep in mind that you are dealing with streams of bytes, not messages.  TCP only guarantees to get the bytes to the far end in the same order and without duplication.  It makes no claims about moving any particular group of bytes together and may split or combine buffers as the network dictates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asynchronous I/O on the socket stream. This is almost exactly what you're asking for - you start a receive operation and give it a callback to call when the receive is complete.

Check out the BeginReceive/EndReceive functions.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of this is yes, of course.

What you want to do is fire up a new thread for each client that connects that then raises events on an event/command thread. You're under no obligation to respond to a request other than (and this is handled by your operating system's TCP/IP stack) sending ACK when you receive a packet (don't worry about this part the OS does this for you and it's part of what makes TCP/IP reliable).

As long as the socket is active you should be able to send back responses to the client, so basically you need to keep the socket active for as long as any command is running.

Here's a list of examples from Microsoft that should show you how to do this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx#Y0